# Confusions regarding Laplace transform

Tags: frequency, fourier, laplace-transform, terminology, damping-factor

We know that Laplace transform has two parts, \$\sigma \$ and \$ j\omega\$.

\$\sigma\$ is the real part
while \$ j\omega\$ is the imaginary part.

Is it okay to say that the term \$\sigma \$ is a damping factor term, while \$ j\omega\$ is a pure sinusoidal (pure frequency) term?

I was reading another question on EE stack exchange at link below:

[Relation and difference between Fourier, Laplace and Z transforms](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86489/relation-and-difference-between-fourier-laplace-and-z-transforms)

I read a sentence and I highlighted that sentence in attached snap. The sentence is:

**Fourier transform F(jω) which is essentially the frequency domain representation of f(t)**

So what does that mean? That a Laplace transform is not a frequency domain representation of f(t)?

[image]

Comment: When you use \$s\rightarrow j\omega\$ to get the frequency response, you are assuming that the transient, \$e^{\sigma t}\$, has decayed to zero (i.e it's the 'steady state' frequency response). \$\sigma\$ must be negative otherwise the system is unstable.

Answer (score 5):

First, what is a transformation? A transform is a mapping of a function in one domain into another domain. To go from one domain to another, you need basis-functions (basis-vectors).

In Fourier transform, the basis-functions are complex exponentials; \$e^{-j\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) - j\sin(\omega t)\$

In Laplace transform, the basis-functions are the product of complex exponentials and decaying exponentials; \$e^{-\sigma t}e^{-j\omega t} = e^{-(\sigma+j\omega) t} = e^{-st}\$.

**Fourier transform**: \$F(j\omega) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega t}f(t) \: \text{d} t \$

**Laplace transform**: \$F(s) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-st}f(t) \: \text{d} t \$

Think about the product inside the integral (\$e^{-j\omega t}f(t)) \$ as an inner product (dot product) between two vectors. A dot product is **large**, if the two vectors are similar to each other. A dot product is **small**, if the two vectors are dissimilar.

Consider the Fourier transform first. Evaluating \$e^{-j\omega t}f(t)\$ we investigate how similar \$f(t)\$ is to \$\big(\cos(\omega t) - j\sin(\omega t)\big) \$ for a single frequency.

Evaluating \$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega t}f(t) \: \text{d} t \$ you get a function telling you how similar \$f(t)\$ is to \$\big(\cos(\omega t) - j\sin(\omega t)\big) \$ for any frequency. We call this function \$F(j\omega)\$.

Let's say there is a frequency \$\omega_0\$ and that \$F(j\omega_0)\$ has a very large value. This means that at \$\omega_0\$, \$f(t)\$ and \$\big(\cos(\omega_0 t) - j\sin(\omega_0 t)\big) \$ are very similar to each. This in turn tells you that a sinusoidal component with frequency \$\omega_0\$ is very present in \$f(t)\$. By plotting \$F(j\omega)\$ as a function of \$\omega\$ you see which frequencies are contained in \$f(t)\$ and also how much each frequency component is present. For this reason, the Fourier transform is an excellent tool for frequency analysis of **signals**.

The same thought process holds for the Laplace transform, however, instead of looking at how similar \$f(t)\$ is to sinusoids, now we look at how similar \$f(t)\$ is to exponentially decaying/growing sinusoids. So \$F(s)\$ is a function telling you how similar \$f(t)\$ is to \$e^{-st}\$ for any \$s\$ and doesn't have the same intuitive usefulness as the Fourier transform does for signal analysis.

However, the Laplace transform is very useful for analysing **systems** since it allows you to use the initial conditions at \$t=0^-\$ for finding the response of a system. The system response you obtain also contain transient components, and not just the steady state response.

The Fourier transform lacks both of these things for system analysis.

**Conclusion**

\$F(j\omega)\$ tells you how similar a function \$f(t)\$ is to sinusoids. The Fourier transform is excellent for **signal** analysis.

\$F(s)\$ tells you how similar a function \$f(t)\$ is to exponentially decaying/growing sinusoids. The Laplace transform is excellent for **system** analysis.

Comment: I think the limits on your Laplace integation are not right

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez The equation for the Laplace I've written in my answer is known as the **bilateral Laplace transform**. However, there also exists the **unilateral Laplace transform** \$F(s) = \displaystyle\int_{0^-}^\infty e^{-st}f(t) \: \text{d}t \$ which is restricted to causal signals only. It turns out that every physical signal you can create irl is causal.

Answer (score 4):

> *So what does that mean? That a Laplace transform is not a frequency
> domain representation of f(t)?*

The Fourier transform is a subset of the Laplace transform. Fourier ignores σ. Laplace is the all-encompassing transform and yes, it encompasses the frequency domain representation of f(t).